# What does blocking means in invokeAll method of executorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

It is said invokeAll is used when we want to wait for completion of all tasks as compared to submit or execute which does not wait.

What do we mean by completion of tasks. Does it mean that parent thread which spawns all other thread get stuck in that point until all the thread returns?

Comment: It means the method returns once the tasks have completed (normally or exceptionally). Each `Callable` in the collection is a task. Which threads are used to execute the task is up to the `ExecutorService`. A typical implementation is a thread pool that will reuse existing threads. How many threads are available or if any are created when a task is submitted depends on how the thread pool is configured.

Answer (score -1):

See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
                          throws InterruptedException
```

Does it mean that parent thread which spawns all other thread get stuck in that point until all the thread returns?

Yes you are right ! see below code this is implementation of invokeAll from AbstractExecutorService.java (oracle JDK8). More importantly you need to notice For loop there. We check if (!f.isDone()) , that means if task is not done (complete) go inside loop and call f.get(), which is blocking call. Effectively you caller of invokeAll is blocked till all tasks are not completed.

```
public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
    throws InterruptedException {
    if (tasks == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    ArrayList<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<T>>(tasks.size());
    boolean done = false;
    try {
        for (Callable<T> t : tasks) {
            RunnableFuture<T> f = newTaskFor(t);
            futures.add(f);
            execute(f);
        }
        for (int i = 0, size = futures.size(); i < size; i++) {
            Future<T> f = futures.get(i);
            if (!f.isDone()) {
                try {
                  f.get();
                } catch (CancellationException ignore) {
                } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
        done = true;
        return futures;
    } finally {
        if (!done)
            for (int i = 0, size = futures.size(); i < size; i++)
                futures.get(i).cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code is a poor way to understand Java SE functionality.  Implementations can change (and have changed) from one Java release to the next, as long as they adhere to the method’s contract.

Comment: Javadoc for invokeall is not clearly saying this is blocking call, probably that is the reason question is asked. Code is added to provide more clarity while explaining. And I understand code can change that is the reason I have given jdk version along with code.

Comment: The javadoc is very clear about it: “Executes the given tasks, **returning** a list of Futures holding their status and results **when all complete**. `Future.isDone()` is `true` for each element of the returned list.” Each of these two sentences implies the blocking behavior.

Comment: In my opinion English sentence could have been written in better way, average people like me can not understand this in first read. Either Blocking keyword should have been there or we can write something like "Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures only when all tasks are complete". Off course futures has isDone to check status, not sure why do we need to add here "Holing their status"